# Pulling DateTime from MySQL: Undefined Index error PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a webpage that I am looking to feed event info from a MySQL Database. I have a PHP function delivering this event info and am trying to include the event's datetime.

The PHP funciton I have currently is feeding information and filling all the `<divs>` except for `<div class="eventdate">`. The function reads:

```
function eventbox() {
$loopResult = "";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT eventname, name, eventicon, DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p') FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id)"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="eventbox">
                <div class="eventtitle">'.$row['eventname'].'</div>
                <div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime)'].'</div>  
                <div class="eventvenue">'.$row['name'].'</div>
                <div class="tie-inbuttonholder">
                    <button type="button">tie-in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="eventboxicon" class="tie-inbutton">'.$row['eventicon'].'</div> 
            </div>  
    '; 
}
echo $loopResult;
}
```

Now the only issue is that when I run the script I get the error code;

> Notice: Undefined index: DATE_FORMAT(eventtime) in /var/www/test/test_func.inc.php on line 23

And line 23 would be:

```
<div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime)'].'</div>
```

I have tried a number of different ways of formatting this part of the function
(that being said i do get slightly different errors running the `.date_format($row...` methods);

```
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ('eventtime'), 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row ['eventtime'], '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.date_format($row['eventtime'], 'l M d\t\h Y \a\t g:iA').'</div>
<div class="eventdate">'.$row['DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y')'].'</div>
etc...
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to correct this issue? When I run the SQL query against my server I get a great table that works perfectly, and all other parts of the function work great.

I saw a lot of poorly rated questions similar to this but nothing specifically like this, I'm sorry if I am re-hashing old material here guys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the result of `DATE_FORMAT()` an alias for easy accessing via PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT eventname, name, eventicon, 
    DATE_FORMAT(eventtime, '%a %b %dth %Y at %h:%i%p') as event_time 
    FROM my_db.events LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING (venue_id) 
    LEFT JOIN my_db.eventtype USING (eventtype_id)");
```

Then in your PHP:

```
<div class="eventdate">'.$row['event_time'].'</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This makes absolute sense, I should have just thought of the SQL syntax surrounding it. Thanks so much for the help. As soon as these 7 minutes are up I will accept your answer haha!